# Connecting to mongodb database in PHP

Tags: php, database, mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Connecting to the mongodb atlas and trying to write a simple document gives the following error. What am I doing wrong?

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://admin:admin@test-shard-00-00-rbgc.mongodb.net:27017/db?ssl=false&replicaSet=test-shard-0&authSource=admin&serverSelectionTryOnce=false");

var_dump($manager);

$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

$bulk->insert(['x' => 1]);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.collection', $bulk);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable
>   servers found: serverselectiontimeoutms timed out: [connection closed
>   calling ismaster on 'test-shard-00-00-waf4c.mongodb.net:27017'] in
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/mongodb/liveserver.php:63

When I var_dump the $manager I get:

> object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#1 (2) { ["uri"]=> string(64)
>   "admin:admin@test-shard-00-00-rbgc.mongodb.net:27017/" ["cluster"]=>
>   array(0) { } }

Comment: Is your mongodb server up and running and correctly configured?

Comment: @KhorneHoly I whitelisted my ip and access to all IPs and also using mongodb Atlas.

Comment: Is it working now @JackRolex?

Comment: @PranshTiwari it was a bug with mongodb needing to update to newest version.

Answer (score 1):

I am using php version 7.0 on ubuntu 16.04. This is a detailed solution. Skip the parts which you have performed successfully.
First I manually installed mongodb and then the mongodb-php driver for it.

1) Installing mongo db. Enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927

$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

In order to properly launch Mongdb as a service, ie automatically starting Mongodb when the system starts, follow the following steps:

Create file mongodb.service in /etc/systemd/system/ by entering the command:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
```

Paste the following contents in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongodb

$ sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

2) Installing the mongo-php driver:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Also you might receive error: phpize not found. Phpize is a command which is used to create a build environment. This error could appear at the time of installation of any pecl extension. To solve this problem of the phpize command not found, the user has to install the php5-dev package. 
To install it enter the command:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
```

Then in the php.ini file which is in /etc/php/7.0/apache2 directory, add the mongo db extension:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Add the following line in the file:

extension = mongodb.so;

(Just so you know, the exact location of the file mongodb.so is in /usr/lib/php/20151012/mongodb.so.)

So the mongo db is installed along with its driver.

3) Now keep in mind that the mongo-php classes have been changed. Most of the available resources in the net give solutions using old classes which is superseded. Below are the links which you can refer to:

http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

http://zetcode.com/db/mongodbphp/

Here are some commands for basic database operations:

```
$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(); // Driver Object created
```

To insert data into the database:

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

$doc = ["_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID, "data" => $someData, "info" => $someInfo];

$bulk->insert($doc);

$mng->executeBulkWrite('dbName.collectionName', $bulk);
```

For fetching data:

```
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]); 

$rows = $mng->executeQuery("dbName.collectionName", $query);

foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {
         echo "$row->data - $row->info\n";
    }
```